# How can I relate an example to the sentence introducing the example

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-combination

The introducing sentence is:

> As an example of the heuristics that are implemented in the algorithm to update a context variable,

The example is:

> the main division surrounding an element is used as the value of the *curblock* variable.

I don't know how can I relate them to each other through one or two sentences.

---

**Update**: I think of this solution:

> The way we update the current block is an example of the heuristics that are implemented in the algorithm. To do so, we use the main division surrounding an element as the value of the current block.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a lot to pack into a single sentence, so you're wise to try to break it up.  If your goal is to emphasize the example, use the first sentence to identify that example and the second to elaborate on it:

> One example of the heuristics implemented in this algorithm is the way we update the current block.  We use the main division surrounding an element as the value of the current block, and then (say something about how this related to your heuristics).

If, on the other hand, your goal is to talk about updating the current block, and the fact that it's an example of your heuristic algorithm is secondary, you can instead lead with the example:

> We update the current block by using the the main division surrounding an element as the value of the current block.  This is an example of the heuristics implemented in this algorithm to update a context variable.

(Without more context I can't tell if what I'm saying about your example is accurate; please focus here on the structure.)